# To List Project Error: Expected the reducer to be a function

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am having trouble with my react/redux project.  I keep getting an error after the code compiles and I can not figure out the issue. This is all pretty new to me and I have been trying to figure this out for a while.  I have installed react and redux at the same time and still getting the same error.  I am not sure where I am going wrong.  Here is my code that I think is the issue:

![enter image description here][1]

```
index.js

    import React from 'react'
    import { render } from 'react-dom'
    import { createStore } from 'redux'
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
    import App from './Components/App'
    import rootReducer from './reducers'
    
    const store = createStore(rootReducer)
    
    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    )


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8O85K.png


Here are my Reducer files:

index.js

    import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
    import todos from './todos'
    import visibilityFilter from './visibilityFilter'
    
    export default combineReducers({
      todos,
      visibilityFilter
    })

todos.js

const todos = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'ADD_TODO':
        return [
          ...state,
          {
            id: action.id,
            text: action.text,
            completed: false
          }
        ]
      case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
        return state.map(todo =>
          (todo.id === action.id)
            ? {...todo, completed: !todo.completed}
            : todo
        )
      default:
        return state
    }
  }
  
  export default todos

todos.spec.js

import todos from './todos'

describe('todos reducer', () => {
  it('should handle initial state', () => {
    expect(
      todos(undefined, {})
    ).toEqual([])
  })

  it('should handle ADD_TODO', () => {
    expect(
      todos([], {
        type: 'ADD_TODO',
        text: 'Run the tests',
        id: 0
      })
    ).toEqual([
      {
        text: 'Run the tests',
        completed: false,
        id: 0
      }
    ])

    expect(
      todos([
        {
          text: 'Run the tests',
          completed: false,
          id: 0
        }
      ], {
        type: 'ADD_TODO',
        text: 'Use Redux',
        id: 1
      })
    ).toEqual([
      {
        text: 'Run the tests',
        completed: false,
        id: 0
      }, {
        text: 'Use Redux',
        completed: false,
        id: 1
      }
    ])

    expect(
      todos([
        {
          text: 'Run the tests',
          completed: false,
          id: 0
        }, {
          text: 'Use Redux',
          completed: false,
          id: 1
        }
      ], {
        type: 'ADD_TODO',
        text: 'Fix the tests',
        id: 2
      })
    ).toEqual([
      {
        text: 'Run the tests',
        completed: false,
        id: 0
      }, {
        text: 'Use Redux',
        completed: false,
        id: 1
      }, {
        text: 'Fix the tests',
        completed: false,
        id: 2
      }
    ])
  })

  it('should handle TOGGLE_TODO', () => {
    expect(
      todos([
        {
          text: 'Run the tests',
          completed: false,
          id: 1
        }, {
          text: 'Use Redux',
          completed: false,
          id: 0
        }
      ], {
        type: 'TOGGLE_TODO',
        id: 1
      })
    ).toEqual([
      {
        text: 'Run the tests',
        completed: true,
        id: 1
      }, {
        text: 'Use Redux',
        completed: false,
        id: 0
      }
    ])
  })

})

visibilityfilter.js

import { VisibilityFilters } from '../actions'

const visibilityFilter = (state = VisibilityFilters.SHOW_ALL, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER':
      return action.filter
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default visibilityFilter
```

Comment: What do the reducer files look like? Can you post this in a sandbox, even if it doesn't work?

Comment: i added the reducer files to my original post.  I will try and create a sandbox, not sure how long that will take.

Comment: I created a sandbox and it seems to work in the sandbox. Not sure what is going in when I use Visual Studio Code.  Not sure what the issue is?https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-benz-evv5y